# Use RegEx to create an input mask

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use RegEx to create an input mask.  The first letter can be either A or B and it has to be 5 digits after the number but ranging from 1-99999.
For example,

A00001

B20000

B00412

This is what I have so far,

```
^[S|T]{1}[0-9]{4}[1-9]
```

but it's not allowing A52210 for example.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why do you want solve this problem by regex?

Comment: `^[AB](?!0{5})\d{5}$`?

Comment: Just seemed the easiest way.  I'm adding the validation on the viewModel in MVC.
     [RegularExpression("^[A|B]{1}[0-9]{4}[1-9]", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be 'S' or 'T' followed by 5 digits.")]

Comment: `^[ST](?!0+$)[0-9]{5}$`

Comment: Thanks for the responses..much appreciated.  ctwheels your solution works.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Brief

I'm not sure what `[S|T]` is supposed to do, but that is saying one of `S|T` - one of `S`, `|`, or `T`. Also the `{1}` is irrelevant and your numbers won't work for the range you expect (`[0-9]{4}[1-9]` says `00001` to `99999`, but not any number followed by a zero, i.e. `11110`).

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/71ufzu/3)

```
^[AB](?!0{5})\d{5}$
```

**Note:** If this regex is to be used on a long string and the contents of the string might include the string you're searching for, you should replace both position assertions `^` and `$` with a word boundary `\b` as per the following regex.

```
\b[AB](?!0{5})\d{5}\b
```

#### Variations

Slightly shorter version, but dependent on end of string (won't work if the string is in the middle of a sentence)

```
^[AB](?!0+$)\d{5}$
```

Negative lookbehind (won't work in some flavours of regex)

```
^[AB]\d{5}(?<!0{5})$
```

Long nuisance regex that checks every possibility, but ensures that at least one number is not `0`

### ^AB$

### Results

#### Input

```
A00001
B20000
B00412
A52210
A00001

A00000
S00001
A1000
```

#### Output

**Note:** Below are matches; anything from `Input` above that isn't here wasn't matched.

```
A00001
B20000
B00412
A52210
A00001
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `[AB]` Match a character from the set (either `A` or `B` literally)
- `(?!0{5})` Ensure what follows isn't `0` five times
- `\d{5}` Match any digit five times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to explain.  RegEx boggles my mind!